# How should I connect GPIO pins to leads to my sensor in a permanent Raspberry Pi deployment?

Tags: gpio, breadboard, case

I have built a small IoT application that runs on my RP. I would like to deploy it permanently in my home, but would like to formalize the breadboard setup into something a little more durable and lasting. What is the right way to do this? Is there a preferred case that allows for screw terminals or perma-proto shield? I would like everything to be as compact as possible.

I am happy to solder as needed.

Comment: I'd have thought solder is by far the best for permanence (although some might say wire-wrap).  It's not really a question for this site though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options that very in flexibility, cost, difficulty etc.

My preferred method is to use a [Pi Cobbler](https://www.adafruit.com/products/914) and a [PermaProto Board](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1135) from Adafruit. You could prototype with a breadboard and then transfer the components to the protoboard and solder the connections to make it more permanent (note there are more suppliers for these parts besides Adafruit, also I linked to the full size protobaord but it does come in smaller sizes).

You could carefully solder wire to the GPIO pins themselves - though I would not recommend this.

You could [wirewrap](http://www.jameco.com/jameco/workshop/techtip/wirewrap.html) the connections (this is the old school method and requires a special tool.

You could create a custom PCB, (either make it yourself or have it manufactured by a company like [OSH Park](https://oshpark.com/)) (when having it made this usually requires a minimum number of boards to be purchased and can be daunting for someone who has not done it before.

Depending on the environment you could just leave it on  a breadboard with jumper wires.

Comment: Thanks, I found this https://www.adafruit.com/products/2310 plus some screw terminals to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: One minor thing I'd add: soldering to the GPIO pins is indeed a bad idea on the original Pis, but on the new pi zero it's quite a reasonable proposition (given the cost of the unit it'd be feasible to buy one per "permanently deployed" application - a colleague has already done this with a unicorn HAT and a pi zero attached to a Babbage bear :-)

Comment: @DaveJones good point as it ships without headers you could solder right to the pads.